# Hide past date and time from date picker swift

Tags: swift, datepicker, datetimepicker, uidatepicker

i'm trying to hide date picker past date. but i m not able to hide. is there any way to hide past date and time. I was able to disable the past date when i have set to minimum date. So is there any way to hide the past date from date picker.

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: You can't hide it the property `minimumDate` disables it, but hiding is not in our hands. You have to create your own picker to add this feature.  `datePicker.minimumDate = Date()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dateCollection = [Date]()

func selectedDate()->Int{
    dateCollection = buildDateCollection()
    var row = 0
    for index in dateCollection.indices{
    let today = Date()
    if Calendar.current.compare(today, to: dateCollection[index], toGranularity: .day) == .orderedSame{
row = index
        }
    }
    return row
}

func buildDateCollection()-> [Date]{
   dateCollection.append(contentsOf: Date.nextYear())
   return dateCollection
}

func formatDatePicker(date: Date) -> String{
    formatter.dateFormat = DATE_PICKER_FORMAT_CUSTOM
    return formatter.string(from: date)
}

func formatDate(date: Date) -> String{
    formatter.dateFormat = SECURIY_CONC_CLIENT_FORMAT_PNDING
    return formatter.string(from: date)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    let _ = selectedDate()
}

func setPickerView() {
    picker.tag = tag
    picker.delegate = self
    txtField_Date.dataSource = self
    txtField_Date.inputView = picker
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
     return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return dateCollection.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return formatDatePicker(date: dateCollection[row])
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
     txtField_Date.text = formatDate(date: self.dateCollection[row])
}
```

Output Screen Shot:

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 8):

Solution :

Set minimum date of date picker as a Current Date.

`datePicker.minimumDate = Date()`

For a reference you can follow this SO questions:

[How to hide future or past dates in UIDatePickerView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33104249/3278326)

[iOS: UIDatePicker "remove" dates outside min and max dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26289633/3278326)

Note: Minimum date property will disable the selection of past dates but it won't hide the dates rather it will grayed out it.